# Reading a record while data is being inserted using transaction in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, transactions

Similar questions have been asked multiple times but I have gone through them and couldn't find a solution.

I am trying to import a simple CSV file containing around 500 orders into my database table. And I am using transactions as shown below.

```
        $dbAdapter->beginTransaction();
        $file = new SplFileObject($fileName, 'r');
        while(!$file->eof()){               
            try{
                $order = $file->fgetcsv();
                if(!$this->orderExists($order)){ 
                     $this->saveOrder($order);
                }
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                $dbAdapter->rollBack();
                throw new Om_Model_Exception($ex->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $dbAdapter->commit();
```

This works fine. But the same CSV file can have duplicate orders and I need to skip them. To do that before inserting the order I am checking the database table to see if the order exists but this always returns false because the transaction is still running.

So my question is, is there a way to check for inserted records before the transaction is committed? (May be MySQL stores data in to a temporary table and I can query that).

I can solve this by storing orders into an array and checking the array for duplicates but this seems like a waste of lot of memory. And might not work properly if the order file is large.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using the same DB connection instance to query and insert? You should already be able to read the data you have inserted but not yet committed as long as you are querying using the same connection that started the transaction. A different connection will be unable to see any uncommitted inserts unless the isolation level is READ UNCOMMITTED

Comment: @Anigel Yes. I am using the same database connection.